# How can I get the map to repeat to fill the screen?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm programming my first ArcGIS application. I've created a simple map. When I zoom out to a world view, the map doesn't fill the width of the screen. Ideally I'd like it to repeat until the available space is filled. How can I do this?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var map = new esri.Map("map", {

basemap: "topo",
center: [0, 0],
zoom: 2
});
```

And here's the result:

[image]

How can I get the map to repeat to fill the white space on either side?

(Crossposted: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/79757-How-can-I-get-the-map-to-repeat-to-fill-the-screen)

**Update**:

I've set the spatial reference to (I think) Web Mercator, and wrapAround180 to true, but this has no effect. New constructor:

```
var map = new esri.Map("map", {
            basemap: "topo",
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2,
            sliderPosition: "bottom-left",
            spatialRefence: new esri.SpatialReference({ "wkid": 3857 }),
            wrapAround180: true
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wrap around 180](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/map.html) means that it will continue to pan as you move along the longitude. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/7V2Cd/4/) for an example (it is true by default). I've never seen ESRI do the repeat map thing, I don't believe it is possible. If you want that feel you could limit the zoom levels so they can't go out beyond a certain zoom level using [LOD's](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/map.html#lod) in the map configuration